# Sorting a 2 dimensional array in c

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I am trying to sort a 2 dimensional array.the original array is

```
5 0 3
4 1 2
3 1 1
4 2 2
3 3 1
```

When sorted, it should be like

```
3 1 1
3 3 1
4 2 2
4 1 2
5 0 3
```

Here is the code i used trying to implement Bubble Sort,i represents the number of rows.

```
int x,y,z,j,temp1,temp2,temp3;
for(x=0;x<i;x++)
{
    for (j=0;j<i-1;j++)
    {
        if(a[j][0]>a[j+1][0])
        {
            temp1=a[j][0];
            temp2=a[j][1];
            temp3=a[j][2];
            a[j][0]=a[j+1][0];
            a[j][1]=a[j+1][1];
            a[j][2]=a[j+1][2];
            a[j+1][0]=temp1;
            a[j+1][1]=temp2;
            a[j+1][2]=temp3;
        }
    }
}
```

it still does not sort, any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your bracket style is curious.

Comment: Why does `4 2 2` come before `4 1 2`?

Comment: A good hint is you don't use the variable `x` outside of its loop.

Comment: Are you trying to sort rows or columns?

Comment: If you are sorting according to first column, then you are simply sorting a 1d array. Lots of algos for that ..

Comment: Changed. Formatting was giving me a headache.

Comment: You've shown what the "correct" output *should* be; care to show us what you're *actually* getting (along with an actual **compilable** sample? (you know, has a `int main(void)`, some `#include`s, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to sort the rows of the array in [lexicographical order](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order).  If you treat the 2D array as an array of arrays, then you are just sorting the second-level arrays within the first-level array into ascending lexicographical order.

Depending on whether the number of columns in your array is fixed, you might be able to do this using the `qsort` function with a custom comparator.  For example, if you know that there will always be exactly 3 elements in each column, you could write a comparator like this one:

```
static const size_t NUM_COLS = 3;

/* Lexicographically compare two arrays of size NUM_COLS. */
int CompareArrays(const void* arr1, const void* arr2) {
     /* Convert back to the proper type. */
     const int* one = (const int*) arr1;
     const int* two = (const int*) arr2;

     /* Do an element-by-element comparison.  If a mismatch is found, report how
      * the arrays compare against one another.
      */
     for (size_t i = 0; i < NUM_COLS; i++) {
         if (one[i] < two[i]) return -1;
         if (one[i] > two[i]) return +1;
     }

     /* If we get here, the arrays are equal to one another. */
     return 0;
}

/* Use qsort to sort the arrays */
qsort((const int*)&one, numRows, sizeof(int[NUM_COLS]), CompareArrays);
```

Hope this helps!