# Multi-Dimensional Array sorting in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

I am using **sort()** function for single array it works well.
I also used this for multi-dimensional array but this is not work.
Here is code:

```
#include <iostream>


 using namespace std;

  int main(){

  int a[2][3];

    a[0][1]=7;
    a[1][0]=1;
    a[1][1]=3;

    sort(a,a+3);

    cout<<a[0][1]<<"\t"<<a[1][0]<<"\t"<<a[1][1];


return 0;
}
```

I know I use single array for these value but this is example and I want it in multi-dimensional array.

Comment: This may or may not help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14092642/sorting-a-2-dimensional-array-in-c

Comment: You should also include the algorithm header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code just use `std::sort` on each row of the multidimensional array. ie.

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(){

  int a[2][3];

  a[0][0]=1;
  a[0][1]=7;
  a[0][2]=3;
  a[1][0]=6;
  a[1][1]=2;
  a[1][2]=5;

  for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
    sort(a[i],a[i]+3);
  }

  for(int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 2; col++) {
      cout << a[row][col] << " ";
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

I initiated every element of your multidimensional array `a`, since your declared `a` to be size 6 (2 rows, 3 columns). This would output `1 3 7 2 5 6`, because it sorts the rows from least to greatest. If you wanted to sort the multidimensional array so that the output would read `1 2 3 5 6 7` then you would need to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main(){

  int a[2][3];
  int b[6];
  int count = 0;

  a[0][0]=1;
  a[0][1]=7;
  a[0][2]=3;
  a[1][0]=6;
  a[1][1]=2;
  a[1][2]=5;

  for(int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
      b[count] = a[row][col];
      count++; 
    }
  }

  sort(b, b+6);
  count = 0;

  for(int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
      a[row][col] = b[count];
      count++;
    }
  }

  for(int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
      cout << a[row][col] << " ";
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

This second example is probably the worst possible way to go about sorting a multidimensional array though. Let me know if you find an error in my code, I was unable to test, or need additional help.

Comment: There is no error except missing semi-colons after that `a[0][0]=1;`

Comment: @Axeem, This will not sort the array, it will just sort each row separately. Is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

As the multidimensional arrays are contiguous you can also try:

```
int main()
{
  int a[2][3];

  a[0][0]=1;
  a[0][1]=7;
  a[0][2]=3;
  a[1][0]=6;
  a[1][1]=2;
  a[1][2]=5;

  std::sort(&a[0][0], &a[1][3]);

  for(int row = 0; row < 2; row++) {
    for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
      std::cout << a[row][col] << " ";
    }
  }
}
```

Depending on what you want. It is also possible to write a `begin()` and `end()` for multidimensional arrays.